# Lenovo Vibe p1m suddenly slow

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, performance, lenovo, lagging

Today I notice my Lenovo Vibe p1m is running slow. It coudn't open Chrome without freezing. The whole UI is basically sluggish. It also couldn't open the flashlight.

I have tried removing the sdcard and restarting in safe mode. Same slowness. I didn't install anything new so it's baffling what could cause it. I also can't open the Update screen of Google play because it freezes. I check the running apps section, RAM usage is just 700MB out of 2GB.

Looks like the phone is basically screwed for no logical reason. The phone is only 1.5 years old.

Any ideas what could cause this and how/what else could I diagnose?

Comment: The same problem happened to me just a few days ago, seems like they screwed up some updates or something.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly this happened to me today, at morning I was watching videos, then I use the mobile again, and i cant even load youtube! Ill try deactivating some apps as phaethon said.

Deactivating some apps and uninstalling some helped, but mobile is still very slow :/

So I decided to factory reset my phone and everything is like normal, I have no clue what was the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

After deactivating playstore and relative apps + whatsapp the pproblem is solved.

I dont activate playsrre again for now until I get a "lenovo" reply

Comment: What is 'a "lenovo" reply'? This isn't a Lenovo site so you won't get an official response here. Lenovo has their own forum if that's what you're looking for.